# Simulating mouse/keyboard events to Hyper-V virtual machine

Tags: c#, winapi, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm running Windows 10 as host machine, and inside of Hyper-V virtual machine with another Windows 10. What I'm trying to do, is write a C# program, that will click the mouse button every 1s, and eventually send some keystrokes from keyboard, like 'abc'.

So far, I tried `PostMessage` with `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and UP with window handle to the hyper-v window, `mouse_event`, but nothing works. `mouse_event` works fine on host machine, clicks every 1s, but once I hover over mouse to virtual machine, it doesnt click anymore.

Is there a way of simulating clicks and keyboard keys in host machine and having  VM react to it?

Comment: far as I read hyper v doesnt let you

Comment: Hi. I'm facing the same problem. on physical machine or hyper-v server, everything is fine, but when it comes to VM there is the bug you mentioned, I'm wondering if you ever solved this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a way to do this through Hyper-V's WMI interface (which can be accessed through PowerShell, which has nice integration with C#).  VirtualPCGuy had a great 10-part blog series about doing this sort of thing with Hyper-V (starting March 7, 2016).  Here are his code samples (in PowerShell) for the specific things you're asking about.

[Typing a String](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2016/03/07/typing-a-string-on-a-virtual-machine/):

```
$VMName = "Windows 10 Enterprise"
$VMCS = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\virtualization\v2 -Class Msvm_ComputerSystem -Filter "ElementName='$($VMName)'"
$keyboard = $VMCS.GetRelated("Msvm_Keyboard")
$keyboard.TypeText("Hello!") | out-null
```

[Controlling the Mouse](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2016/03/11/controlling-the-mouse-on-a-virtual-machine/):

```
$VMName = "Windows 10 Enterprise"
$VMCS = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\virtualization\v2 -Class Msvm_ComputerSystem -Filter "ElementName='$($VMName)'"
$mouse = $VMCS.GetRelated("Msvm_SyntheticMouse")
$mouse.SetAbsolutePosition(300,450) | out-null
$mouse.ClickButton(2) | out-null
```

Note: this will only work in basic mode, not enhanced mode.  If you're interested in doing more advanced stuff, I highly recommend reading the entire series.

Disclaimer: work at Microsoft on the Hyper-V engineering team.

Comment: Strangely I'm getting gibberish on my CentOS VM with `TypeText`. `TypeKey` (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2016/03/09/typing-special-characters-on-a-virtual-machine/) works OK for single keypresses though.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing as @mwfearnley on an Ubuntu 20.04 VM.

Comment: Also a note for future readers that this only works in Windows PowerShell.  It will result in `...[Deserialized.System.Management.ManagementObject#root\virtualization\v2\Msvm_ComputerSystem] does not contain a method named 'GetRelated'` on PowerShell Core.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds try to run as administrator.
On another note; Couldn't get this to work with a Linux guest. Does it have any prerequisites? It simply did not enter the typed text, but did not fail. All variables/objects populated.

Comment: @dza I'm not the author of this answer (just the comment you replied to), so I don't recall the details of this one.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I was trying to address your issue. I got the same exact message if I ran in unelevated prompt so I'm pretty sure all you had to do was run as admin.

Comment: @dza Ah, thank you!  I read it wrong (mainly focused on the last half).  I'll be honest; I can't even remember what problem I was trying to solve when I tried this!  I'm sure it was something I thought would be a workaround to some other problem I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to joslack's answer and thanks to mwfearnley's references:

If you require more consecutive calls to the TypeText or TypeKey functions, try adding a small delay between each call (i.e. `sleep -Milliseconds 100`). For Example:

```
$VMName = "Windows 10 Enterprise"
$VMCS = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\virtualization\v2 -Class Msvm_ComputerSystem -Filter "ElementName='$($VMName)'"
$keyboard = $VMCS.GetRelated("Msvm_Keyboard")
$keyboard.TypeKey(0x70) | out-null
sleep -Milliseconds 100
$keyboard.TypeKey(0x09) | out-null
sleep -Milliseconds 100
$keyboard.TypeKey(0x32) | out-null
sleep -Milliseconds 1200
```

Credits to [Ben Armstrong’s Virtualization Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/typing-special-characters-on-a-virtual-machine)

[Full list of virtual keycodes here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes?redirectedfrom=MSDN)